# React Redux - Error on render because expecting props that didn't arrive yet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, render, lifecycle

After fetching the data from an API, and putting that data on the Redux state, I'm using a helper function in `mapStatetoProps` to select and modify part of that data and pass it modified to the `props`.

So without the rendering I can see in the `console.log` that everything goes as it should.

1. Empty props: `this.props.pageContent = {}`
2. The data fetch and mapped to props: `this.props.pageContent = { pageSection: [{something here that I don't want}, {}, {}...] }`
3. The data as I want it selected and passed to the props: `this.props.pageContent = { pageSection: [{card: 'my Data'}, {}, {}...] }`

but when I pass some `props`to a component it throws an error because those `props` that I'm trying to pass haven't arrived yet to `this.props` (in this case `card.cardTitle`)

This is my code so far:

```
class Page extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.fetchPageContent();
  }
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.pageContent)
        if (!this.props.pageContent.pageSection[0].card) return null;
    return (
      <div>
        <PageSection
          introSectionCardTitle={ this.props.pageContent.pageSection[0].card.cardTitle}
          introSectionCardContent={ this.props.pageContent.pageSection[0].card.cardContent}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Any ideas?
before the `return` I tried to have an `if` statement with diferent options, but the error keeps the same: 
`TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Comment: post `mapStateToProps`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a problem here `if (!this.props.pageContent.pageSection[0].card)`

replace

`if (!this.props.pageContent.pageSection[0].card)`

with

`if(this.props.pageContent && this.props.pageContent.pageSection && this.props.pageContent.pageSection[0].card)`

Because you are not sure that your props has `pageContent` and you are also not sure that `pageSection` exist, because before setting the props `pageContent` is `undefined` and you are trying to access an object inside it and then find element inside an array

Try the updated code below:

```
class Page extends Component {
      componentWillMount() {
        this.props.fetchPageContent();
      }
      render() {
        console.log(this.props.pageContent)
        if(this.props.pageContent && this.props.pageContent.pageSection && this.props.pageContent.pageSection[0].card)
        {
            return (
              <div>
                <PageSection
                  introSectionCardTitle={ this.props.pageContent.pageSection[0].card.cardTitle}
                  introSectionCardContent={ this.props.pageContent.pageSection[0].card.cardContent}
                />
              </div>
            );
        }
        else
        {
            return (<div></div>);
        }

      }
```

Comment: Thanks! it felt a bit weird having to check every nested key in that object, but the solution is working. 